# Select multiple color pointers at gradient tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, selections

I need to keep a gradient in equal distances in between colors. an example:
[image]

So I want move all purple pointers together, instead one by one.

This is a simple example, sometimes it gets more intensive than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no** mechanism in Illustrator to move more than one gradient stop at a time.

You can manually input values in the `Location` field on the panel to adjust the distance between stops if needed.